# How to avoid this "'tuple' object has no attribute 'photo'" error in my custom User module?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I'm trying to store additional information about 
users that login with facebook to my site, so I created a
UserProfile model.

This is how I define the UserProfile:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    photo = models.TextField()

    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

    post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'blog.UserProfile'
```

And, since I'm using python-social-auth for the authentication, I'm implementing
a custom pipeline to store the image url of the user in the UserProfile.

```
from blog.models import UserProfile

def get_profile_picture(
    strategy,
    user,
    response,
    details,
    is_new=False,
    *args,
    **kwargs
    ):
    img_url = 'http://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large' \
        % response['id']
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user = user)
    profile.photo = img_url
    profile.save()
```

But I'm getting following error:
'tuple' object has no attribute 'photo'

I know the UserProfile has the attribute "photo" because 
this is the definition of that table:

```
table|blog_userprofile|blog_userprofile|122|CREATE TABLE "blog_userprofile" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "user_id" integer NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"),
    "photo" text NOT NULL
)
```

What it's wrong with my code then?

Comment: Are you sure that UserProfile.objects.get_or_create() returns a UserProfile object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the error states, your `profile` variable is a tuple, not a UserProfile instance. That is because `get_or_create` returns a tuple of (instance, created).

Comment: thanks, this worked: profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user = user)[0]